# jQuery action detected without action

Tags: jquery, mouseover

This is my problem. Every time I load the page, I get an alert message with "Click" and I just can't understand what am I doing wrong. I have not clicked. Same happens with mouseover or any function I add.

```
<script>
    $jq().ready( function(){
        $jq( ".clickable" ).click( alert( "Click" ) );
        // Hide all the questions and answers
        $jq( ".faq-section" ).each(
            function(){ $jq(this).css( "display", "none" ); }
        );
    });
</script>
```

I apologise if this is an stupid question.

Comment: As a side note, your `.each` can be eliminated - `.css` will internally do an `.each` loop so that `.css` is applied on all selected elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of this line `$jq( ".clickable" ).click( alert( "Click" ) );`. Instead of passing a function reference you are calling the function here.

Change it to

```
$jq( ".clickable" ).click(function(){ 
     alert( "Click" );
     //do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 $jq( ".clickable" ).click( alert( "Click" ) );
```

should be

```
 $jq( ".clickable" ).click(function(e){ alert( "Click" ); e.preventDefault(); } );
```